# Cannot recover "Trashed" files in 13.04 64 bit

Tags: trash

I was working on external hard-disk and my computer stopped responding.

I unplugged the cables of the USB harddisk and forced the system to power off. On restarting the system i discovered the directory I was working on  was missing.

It was in the Trash folder. I tried to restore it but it  "could not determine original location of "myfolder".

How do I restore this item from trash ?

Comment: Plug the external hdd in, wait a few seconds and then try to restore the deleted folder from trash.

Answer (score 0):

You should try restoring again with the external drive plugged in. Files in the "Trash" are stored inside a hidden ".Trash" folder at the root of each external drive you plug in. Much the same way the "Recycle Bin" works on windows.

Answer (score 0):

On some External drives the trash file is hidden on the drive itself and not on your computer.

Navigate to your external drive on your "Home" Folder.  Press `[Ctrl H]` to reveal hidden files.

You should now see a folder named ".trash".  Within than folder there will be sub-folders called "expunged" and files.  You will find any files you have deleted in there.

You can then restore them